Reason for 19F NMR of OsO2F3 chemical shift
I have been learning that the $\ce{^{19}F}$-NMR spectrum of $\ce{[OsO2F3]^+}$ cation shows two sets of signals. There is a doublet and a triplet which accurately depicts that there are two axial fluorine and an equatorial fluorine which is coplanar with two $\ce{Os=O}$ bonds:


(Casteel et al.)
Since the question is still unattracted, I have found out some paper to improve the question. In this paper, some $\ce{^{19}F}$-NMR spectra of ReOF5 and IOF5 could be found:

In ReOF5 the quintet is greatly shifted to high field from the doublet, whereas in IOF5 the quintet lies slightly to low field of the doublet.


This phenomenon is explained by the availability of the d-orbital

It may be supposed that in ReF7 and WF6,where vacant 5d-orbitals are available, the σ-bonding of the ligands is supplemented by pπ-dπ bonding and that in the iodine fluorides there will be no such supplementation. The π-bonding will reduce the polarity of the fluorine-central atom bond and cause the 19F resonance to be moved to lower field

So clearly, in $\ce{[OsO2F3]^+}$, the d-orbitals of osmium are available for the pπ-dπ bonding. I figure that the equatorial fluorine will be more negatively charged than the axial fluorine (the effect of oxygen atom). This lead to a conclusion that the equatorial fluorine is shifted to high field, similar with IOF5. However it is a bit contrariant in this case.
A noticeable explanation is quoted:

Since an oxygen ligand is a better electron donor than a fluorine ligand the oxygen rhenium pπ-dπ bonds will be the strongest in ReOF5 molecule. The oxygen will have two p-orbitals disposed for interaction with two d-orbitals of the rhenium. If the Re-O axis is taken as the z-axis, the latter orbitals will be dzy and dzx. Those are also the only d-orbitals which the axial fluorine ligand can use in bonding. The equatorial fluorine ligands, however, can interact with the dxy-orbital, which is not available to the oxygen. Multiple bonding by the oxygen will therefore considerably diminish the possibility of pπ-dπ bonding by the axial fluorine. The axial fluorine-rhenium bond should, in consequence, be more polar than the equatorial bonds and the axial 19F resonance should, therefore, be to high field of the equatorial resonance.

This explanation fairly accords with the observation of $\ce{[OsO2F3]^+}$ structure. So I guess it is depends on the structure of the compound that some of the effects listed above should dominate and result in the observed spectrum. Is that right?
Casteel, W. J.; Dixon, D. A.; Mercier, H. P. A.; Schrobilgen, G. J. The Osmium(VIII) Oxofluoro Cations $\ce{OsO2F3^+}$ and $\ce{F($cis$-OsO2F3)2^+}$: Syntheses, Characterization by $\ce{^{19}F}$ NMR Spectroscopy and Raman Spectroscopy, X-Ray Crystal Structure of $\ce{F($cis$-OsO2F3)2^+Sb2F11^-}$, and Density Functional Theory Calculations of $\ce{OsO2F3^+}$, $\ce{ReO2F3}$, and $\ce{F($cis$-OsO2F3)2^+}$. Inorg. Chem. 1996, 35, 4310–4322. https://doi.org/10.1021/ic951059n.
19F N.M.R. SPECTRA OF HEPTAVALENT FLUORIDES AND OXIDE PENTAFLUORIDES. Canadian Journal of Chemistry
https://doi.org/10.1139/v64-371

In general you expect atoms in different environments to have different shifts. Are you asking for an explanation of why they have these specific shifts?

Yes, that is right

For future reference: for the body of questions, answers, and comments, chemistry.se offers to use mhchem as a comfortable method to add chemical equations and report numerical values (\pu{}) including a non-breakable space.

Do you know about nuclear spin in NMR spectroscopy? There is net spin of $\ce{^1H} = 1/2$ and $\ce{^{19}F} = 1/2$, i.e. one equatorial F couples with two axial F (and hence the coupling pattern yields a triplet), etc.

I am aware of that, I was not wondering about their multiplicity but their chemical shift

The F atoms are in chemical environments (distance, electronic density), their nuclei are differently (de)shielded and hence their signals' centers show up at different chemical shift. Relatable to e.g., $\ce{C-H}$ of a methyl group vs. $\ce{C-H}$ of a carbonyl group in $\ce{^1H}$ NMR spectra.

Thanks for your answer. But thats a general reason for different chemical shift. May I ask, in detail, about the electronic density. I noticed that O(2-) is a strong pi-donating ligand and this increase the electron density on osmium which weakens the Os-F bond. Does this add up to the reason?
